# Align 3 divs one div has fixed width

Tags: css, html, alignment

I want to align 3 divs in a same row with the first div having a fixed width.

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='div1' style='width:300px'> </div>
<div id='div2'> </div>
<div id='div3'> </div>
</div>
```

**The other two divs fill the remaing space.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell;` for the child `div's` and a `display:table` for the parent `div` id `container`.

This will align the div in one line keeping the relative widths of the other div to fill.

Here is the [WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qGSMs/1/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div1" style="width:300px; background: gray;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="div2" style="background: #cccccc;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="div3" style="background: #eeeeee;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#container{display:table; width:100%;}
#container div{display:table-cell;}
```

Comment: This will also render HTML whitespace between in the DOM, throwing out other width calculations or breaking the coherency of the design.

Comment: You can remove them by setting font-size of `.container` to 0px, and restoring it in `.container *`.

Comment: Sorry. I was creating a working solution. I have updated my answer - @Doug

Comment: Yes. I just saw your update. I have updated my solution - @Jacob

Comment: My initial comment is rendered completely nonsensical now because you've completely changed your approach from inline-block ;)

Comment: Just as an aside, it's funny how 10 years ago we all steered away from table layout because it was considered non-semantic and clunky. After a decade of trying to make DIV layouts work in all situations we end up going full circle and using table layouts again, albeit via CSS, because I guess there are some situations where they just work (as much as I hate to admit it!)

Answer (score 1):

u have to add float: left;

Exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/nDnqn/

css:

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The other divs don't take up the remaining width though.

Comment: he edited after "The other two divs fill the remaing space."  and i didnt update becouse Nathan Lee already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... http://jsfiddle.net/3XPkT/

Basically, if you're prepared to wrap the first column in the second then it's fairly straight forward

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='div2'>
    <div id='div1'>Col 1</div>
    Col 2
  </div>
  <div id='div3'>Col 3</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS...

```
#div1{background:#999;width:300px;float:left}
#div2{background:#bbb;width:50%;float:left}
#div3{background:#ddd;width:50%;float:left}
#footer{clear:both;}
```

There are other tricks like using absolute postioning but that will break any footer you want to add.

You might fall into slight difficulties if the left hand column is very short - the content of the middle column will wrap underneath - but that can be solved by a touch of javascript if necessary.